# When does the Yufuin no mori train run?

Tags: trains, japan, kyushu, jr-passes

We will be travelling to Yufuin and Beppu in Mid November and we were wondering if the Yufuin no mori train will be running then. I've seen somewhere that it is seasonal, but I can't find what that means.

November in Japan is autumn leaves season.

We want to catch the morning train (I believe the first train leaves at 9:24am from Hakata in Fukuoka).

Also, if how much extra is it to sit at the front in the panorama area?

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment because it doesn't answer your question, but note that all seats on the Yufuin no Mori are reserved, so you must make a reservation prior to boarding. (Of course, reservations are free with a JR Pass.) Also, since those trains are quite popular, the earlier you make the reservation, the better (although this may not matter as much if you plan to take it on a weekday).

Comment: @fkraiem we have changed our plans to a Sunday, so we'll have to book as soon as we get the Japan Rail pass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [the official site](http://www.jrkyushu.co.jp/trains/yufuinnomori/), **trains run three times a day, every day of the year** (毎日運転).  However, there are a few periods when some runs of the special train with wood paneling and panorama windows etc are replaced by an 'ordinary' express:

1. Nr. 1/2/5/6 replaced: Sep 9-11, Nov 17-21, Jan 13-Feb 13
2. Nr. 3/4 replaced: Oct 6-10, Dec 16-18

Do note that while all three trains run from Fukuoka (Hakata) to Yufuin, the Yufuin-Beppu bit of the route is served only once per day by Nr. 3/4.

Re: pricing, my understanding is that all seats are the same price, and the panorama section is open to all.

Comment: Great concise answer. I found the yufuin no mori train on the 16th and have adjusted accordingly. Hopefully we don't need too much advance notice to get tix.